# Python 3.5 Installation Fail on Windows 7 32 bit operating system

Tags: python, windows, 32-bit, python-3.5

I'm having trouble installing Python 3.5 on my 5 years old Windows 7 32-bit operating system laptop. It shows an error message that says:

Setup Failed

0x80240017 - Unspecified Error

I have no problems installing it on my office computer, which is running a 64-bit OS.

I had tried many different ways, even reformatting my laptop just to install Python 3.5 but to no avail. Any kind souls willing to help me with this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What Python bundle are you using? (python.org, Anaconda, Enthought, ActivePython, etc.) And what are you seeing in your application and system logs?

Comment: Facility code 36 (0x24) is [FACILITY_WINDOWSUPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198), and the code is [`WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938205) - "operation was not performed because there are no applicable updates". If you check the installation log in your `%TEMP%` directory, I'm sure you'll see that the [Universal CRT update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48234) failed. This update requires [Windows 7 SP1](http://windows.microsoft.com/installwindows7sp1).

Comment: I am using the bundle from python.org

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the installer, you can try the [embeddable zip file](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/python-3.5.0-embed-win32.zip)!

Comment: Does not work. It returns an error message that says: ' The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling it the program to fix this. '